# Flutter Web RenderRepaintBoundary toimage does not render widgets with images

Tags: flutter, png, render, flutter-web, snapshot

```
RepaintBoundary(
      key: snapshotContainer,
      child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9'),
);
```

and

```
final RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
                          snapshotContainer.currentContext!
                              .findRenderObject()! as RenderRepaintBoundary;
                          final ui.Image image =
                              await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 2);
                          final ByteData? byteData = await image.toByteData(
                              format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
                          final Uint8List pngBytes =
                          byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();
```

produces an empty image. is there a way how to render widgets with images inside via Flutter Web CanvasKit?

Comment: Hello, did you happen to find a solution for this? I'm facing the same problem. Looks like it started when i upgraded to null safety sdk

Comment: I have scoured many a blog/issue/comment but still cannot find a workaround or fix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run flutter in production run mode to see this working. We have been facing the same issue and it seems if you run it using this command

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer canvaskit --release --dart-define=BROWSER_IMAGE_DECODING_ENABLED=false
```

it should render your images.

Word of caution is that the BROWSER_IMAGE_DECODING_ENABLED=false is a workaround for an active issue in flutter

Comment: this worked for me, where can we follow the issue. is it on git hub?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to use svg instead of png images, e.g.

```dart
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart'; 

SvgPicture.asset(AppImages.mapPin, height: 20)
```

This works for Web without any other command line arguments or any other changes.